# Is there a formula for having a number in one cell be represented as a range in another cell by adding and subtracting numbers to it?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a number in one cell, for example 2.6, and in the adjacent cell I would like it shown as 2.1 to 4.6 (maybe displayed as 2.1-4.6 in the cell).  This 'range' comes from subtracting 0.5 from the original number and adding 2.0 to the original number. As my original number changes (gets updated) fairly frequently, I would love if my 'range' would automatically update as well when I change the original number.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Use the string concatenation operator `&`, like this:

`=A2 - 0.5 & "-" & A2 + 2`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that `G2` is the cell containing the number to be evaluated, the formula could be:

```
= G2-0.5 & " - " & G2+2.0
```

Of course, a similar formula would work well even if it were necessary to obtain a range based on percentages of cell `G2`. Ask if you will need it.